# Where can I find more info on decoding a SPNEGO / SSPI packet?

Tags: spnego, sspi

I am trying to gather some information from captured TDS (Tabular Data Stream) data packets.

I am happy with the TDS format, but I am struggling a bit trying to find out how to interpret/decode some of the SSPI Data. (As it happens, they come from Microsoft SQL Server, but my problem is with SSPI)

It would seem that some SSPI packets (e.g. if I connect to "ServerName") are simple **NTLMSSP** format ...

I can deal with these ( mostly by following the [NTLMSSP documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236639.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) )

...

However, some packets (e.g. if I connect to the server by "IP+port"  ) seem to contain additional information "before" the NTLMSSP info, and I'm not sure what this is (or where to find more information)

I have found a few references to [SPNEGO - RFC4178](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4178) but am not sure how this helps.

I am also struggling to find a good "worked example"

**Q: Can anyone help?** (Either with the decoding or with a reference/worked-example)

---

Client Example:

```
0000 - (   0) :   A1 77 30 75 A0 03 0A 01   01 A2 5A 04 58 4E 54 4C -- [.w0u......Z.XNTL]
0010 - (  16) :   4D 53 53 50 00 03 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 58 00 00 -- [MSSP.........X..]
0020 - (  32) :   00 00 00 00 00 58 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 58 00 00 -- [.....X.......X..]
0030 - (  48) :   00 00 00 00 00 58 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 58 00 00 -- [.....X.......X..]
0040 - (  64) :   00 00 00 00 00 58 00 00   00 15 C2 88 E2 06 03 80 -- [.....X..........]
0050 - (  80) :   25 00 00 00 0F 50 B6 46   89 5A 53 3E DB 58 2D 16 -- [%....P.F.ZS>.X-.]
0060 - (  96) :   35 F9 67 3F 9C A3 12 04   10 01 00 00 00 F5 17 A7 -- [5.g?............]
0070 - ( 112) :   50 2D 22 9A 84 00 00 00   00 -- [P-"......]
```

Server Example:

```
0000 - (   0) :   ED F3 00 A1 81 F0 30 81   ED A0 03 0A 01 01 A1 0C -- [......0.........]
0010 - (  16) :   06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 82   37 02 02 0A A2 81 D7 04 -- [..+.....7.......]
0020 - (  32) :   81 D4 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53   50 00 02 00 00 00 08 00 -- [..NTLMSSP.......]
0030 - (  48) :   08 00 38 00 00 00 15 C2   8A E2 32 75 B3 43 9D 33 -- [..8.......2u.C.3]
0040 - (  64) :   06 EF 80 AF 29 C4 E5 00   00 00 94 00 94 00 40 00 -- [....).........@.]
0050 - (  80) :   00 00 06 03 80 25 00 00   00 0F 53 00 57 00 2D 00 -- [.....%....S.W.-.]
0060 - (  96) :   33 00 02 00 08 00 53 00   57 00 2D 00 33 00 01 00 -- [3...     etc ...
```